# Laravel artisan command not working

Tags: php, laravel

I've created my laravel project with create-project beacause `composer install` didn't work.

`cd` to my project and then, when I try to use `php artisan list` or any artisan command it just says:

> Could not open input file: artisan

How do I fix this? the vendor file is in the project

My composer.json:

```
{
  "name": "vendor_name/package_name",
  "description": "description_text",
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "author's name",
      "email": "email@example.com"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.0"
  }
}
```

path to my project:

> c:\wamp\www\project1

Inside vendor, no folder named artisan is showed

Answer (score 1):

**Use the project's root folder**

Artisan comes with Laravel by default, if your php command works fine, then the only thing you need to do is to navigate to the project's root folder. The root folder is the parent folder of the app folder. For example:

```
cd c:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\your-project-name
```

Now the `php artisan list` command should work fine, because PHP runs the file called `artisan` in the project's folder.

**Now install the laravel framework**

Keep in mind that Artisan runs scripts stored in the `vendor` folder, so if you installed Laravel without Composer, like downloading and extracting the Laravel [GitHub repo for laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel), then you don't have the framework itself and you may get the following error when you try to use Artisan:

## `Could not open input file: artisan`

To solve this you have to install the framework itself by running composer install in your project's root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do a "ls" (linux) or a "dir" (win) to make sure you are in the correct folder?

Check if you have correctly installed php.

Run cmd or shell and try to run

> php -v

I'm going to assume you have Windows as your OS.

Go to Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced system settings.

Then go to Environment Variables, find "Path" and add

> ;your/path/to/php.exe

at the end.

Replace "your/path/to/" with your current php.exe directory (including C:\ )

EDIT
Try with this one:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.0"           
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm in the correct folder,and when I do php -v version is OK. I tried to adding the path and It didn't fix anything.

Comment: Plenty of times: Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

Comment: Sure no problem. I edited my answer, with another version (L5) of composer.json. Do a composer update, and try again.

Comment: [RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "database" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder
thats what It throws when I do the composer install

Comment: Mmmmh what laravel version are you using?

Comment: Last one. I tried adding to my composer.json the require laravel and then updated but still no artisan command.

Comment: What PHP version do you have? Have you already tried  to re-download laravel? 
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist

Comment: 5.5.12, tried to re-download laravel, same problem.

Comment: > php artisan key:generate that is showed after I create the laravel project, but no artisan folder or commands working

Answer (score 0):

I'm using windows 10, today is 31st dec, 2016.

I had the same issue, did a bit of a research and solved it.
First go to vendor directory from your laravel project directory and run this command:

```
composer install
```

if it further shows an error and asks for the `composer.json` file missing then:

```
cd ../ 
composer install
```

This fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this has been solved, but I found this to be useful:

```
   composer require laravel/passport --ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo
```